# How many languages are there in 'Young Royals'?

Tags: dialogue, young-royals

I know that *Young Royals* is based in Sweden, but it also contains certain phrases/characters in other languages. The ones I know of are:

- Swedish
- English
- Spanish

Are there any other languages, and if so what are they?

---

I asked this question as I was wondering whether it is possible to fully understand the whole series without subtitles and playing the original sound. How many languages would someone have to learn?

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE**: Context has now been added.